# Heroku log - error H10 while deploying dashboard

Tags: heroku, plotly, gunicorn, plotly-dash

I follow the instruction from [this article](https://medium.com/@austinlasseter/how-to-deploy-a-simple-plotly-dash-app-to-heroku-622a2216eb73), but my code give me the error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-woodland-02831.herokuapp.com request_id=0c26d197-66d8-4c20-9a1d-f6357d771aee fwd="81.5.122.217" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-05-28T17:30:24.573582+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-woodland-02831.herokuapp.com request_id=877a92c7-573b-4d35-90ff-338bbab28fba fwd="81.5.122.217" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I found that problem could be in Procfile but no changes help and I had even tried to copy all code and files from the article Git. But still have the same issue.

I also have in heroku logs this:

```
2020-05-28T17:30:14.228953+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-05-28T17:30:14.228999+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

But didn`t cope with the debugging.

Locally both codes work perfect. Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some mysterious way me helpped reboot of PC. I hope it will help for someone in future.